# Cannot boot after failure to shutdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Ubuntu 18.04 failed to shut down and upon restart it failed to boot. It opened a shell instead of showing GRUB. I have a dual boot with Windows in UEFI mode, and Exit 2 times boots Windows (no problems there).

I'm quite new to Ubuntu, and don't see a way out of this one..

Boot repair didn't work. Setting boot from windows (`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`) didn't work. `ls` command works on the disk but my files/folder differ from the examples because of UEFI.

I can change the boot order/prio in BIOS but booting ubuntu gives a shell instead of GRUB menu..
screenpicture: https://pasteboard.co/HKpNTQx.jpg
After that I get GRUB.
Screenpicture: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HKpQdOL.jpg

Any suggestions?